# Type annotation required

Tags: f#

I have the following:

```
let GetDateTime() = System.DateTime.UtcNow


let InternalHandle dependencies =
    let getDateTime = dependencies

    let future = getDateTime()
    let future = getDateTime().AddDays(float 5)
    printf "The time is %A" future
    ()



let Handle() =
    let dependencies = (GetDateTime)

    InternalHandle dependencies


Handle();;
```

but I am compiler error with "getDateTime().AddDays(float 5)" regarding type annotation.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

getDateTime is a function and I cant add a type annotation.

I am baffled why it does not pick up its a function that returns a DateTime and therefore all functions like AddDays would be available

Comment: Of course you can annotate functions.  Is the question why you need `float 5?` or on the return type?

Comment: when i add "AddDays" it will not complie

Comment: and if I do getDateTime:DateTime i get error This expression was expected to have type
    DateTime    
but here has type
    unit -> DateTime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When doing type inference on functions, the F# compiler does not look at how the function is called later on. This means that when inferring type for `InternalHandle`, it only sees this:

```
let InternalHandle dependencies =
    let getDateTime = dependencies    
    let future = getDateTime()                   // (#1)
    let future = getDateTime().AddDays(float 5)  // (#2)
    printf "The time is %A" future
```

From this, it can infer that `dependencies` is a function (because it is called in #1), but it does not know what the function returns. When it gets to (#2), it sees that you want to invoke `AddDays` method on the result - but this is not enough to decide what the result type is (it could be any .NET object that has this method...). For this reason, you need a type annotation to specify what object are you expecting. You can write:

```
let InternalHandle (dependencies : unit -> System.DateTime) =
    let getDateTime = dependencies    
    let future = getDateTime()
    let future = getDateTime().AddDays(float 5)
    printf "The time is %A" future
```